# Symfony How to get class annotation routing parameter from action

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

Have a problem here:

```
/**
 * Deal controller.
 *
 * @Route("/portfolio/{portfolio_id}/deal")
 */
class DealController extends Controller
{
    // … some code here…

    /**
     * Creates a new Deal entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="mb_deal_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("MBPortfolioBundle:Deal:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
    }
```

So this is my question: how to get $portfolio_id route parameter defined in class annotation from within this createAction?

If I'm trying just add this parameter to the parameter list - it's null then:

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $portfolio_id) // no way
```

If I'm trying to get it from query parameter bag - it's null then:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $portfolio_id = $request->query->get('portfolio_id'); // no way
```

So what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've already found the solution but it doesn't hurt to put here another way to solve it:

```
$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$portfolio_id = $context->getParameter('portfolio_id');
```

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getParameter() on a non-object. It says that fromRequest is a void function :(

Comment: thank you, that's right now, but it started working with just variable in function parameters……… weird

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Move `portfolio_id` to actions' annotation

```
/**
 * Deal controller.
 *
 */
class DealController extends Controller
{

// … some code here…

/**
 * Creates a new Deal entity.
 *
 * @Route("/portfolio/{portfolio}/deal", name="mb_deal_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("MBPortfolioBundle:Deal:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, Portfolio $portfolio)
{
}
```

Comment: thank you for the time spent, got a solution myself, voted for your answer though

Comment: tried to move parameter off class annotation, but it has 5 more actions which need this parameter :(

Comment: @SergeVelikanov Understood.

Answer (score 1):

Mine solution is right here:

```
$portfolio_id = $request->attributes->get('_route_params')['portfolio_id'];
```

Comment: `$request->get('portfolio_id')` should get this for you too.